# What is the probability of each cell being "True" in this table?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say I have a table with the following values.
The following things must be true:

1. Each column must have 3 Trues
2. Each row must have 1 True

```
                   |     1     |      2    |      3    |     4     |     5     |     6     |      7
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         Apple     |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |     True
         Banana    |    False  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |    False  |  -------  |    False
         Car       |     True  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False
         Dinosaur  |    False  |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |  -------  |    False
         Elephant  |    False  |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |  -------  |    False
         Fig       |     True  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False
         Giraffe   |    False  |    False  |     True  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False
         Hound     |    False  |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |    False  |  -------
         Ice       |    False  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |    False  |  -------  |  -------
         Jay       |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |     True  |    False
         Kangaroo  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |  -------  |  -------
         Leopard   |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |     True  |    False
         Moose     |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |     True  |    False  |    False
         Numbat    |    False  |    False  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |    False  |  -------
         Octopus   |    False  |    False  |    False  |     True  |    False  |    False  |    False
         Pig       |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |  -------  |  -------
         Quinoa    |    False  |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |    False  |  -------
         Rhino     |     True  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False
         Snake     |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |     True  |    False  |    False
         Tapeworm  |    False  |    False  |    False  |    False  |     True  |    False  |    False
         Unicorn   |    False  |    False  |    False  |     True  |    False  |    False  |    False
```

The "-------" mark unknown cells.

Is it possible to figure out the probability of any unknown cell being true?

Or, figure out the number of solutions this table could have, then examine each solution and count the number of "True" occurrences for any given unknown cell, and then divide that count by the number of solutions?

Comment: it feels like a sudoku. I am looking forward to see the answers

Comment: Hopefully it's possible to answer. Starting to think it's not...

Comment: Do you mind providing a bit of context? Where did this problem originate?

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to putting the $21$ items into $7$ bins such that each bin contains exactly $3$ items. A `True` in a cell indicates that the item in this cells row is put into the bin corresponding to the cells column.

Since the bins $1$ and $5$ are already full and some items are already placed, we can simplify the problem to this:

```
           |   bin 2   |   bin 3   |   bin 4   |   bin 6   |  bin  7
           |  3 items  |  2 items  |   1 item  |   1 item  |  2 items
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Banana    |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |  -------  |    False
 Dinosaur  |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |    False
 Elephant  |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |    False
 Hound     |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |  -------
 Ice       |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |  -------  |  -------
 Kangaroo  |    False  |    False  |    False  |  -------  |  -------
 Numbat    |    False  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |  -------
 Pig       |    False  |    False  |    False  |  -------  |  -------
 Quinoa    |  -------  |  -------  |  -------  |    False  |  -------
```

At this point I can't reach any further conclusions or simplifications. You might want to use a computer to find all valid solutions. Then you can calculate all the probabilities you like using the method described in your question.